# Is it possible to view the script that Visual Studio runs to build a solution or project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to write a script that creates a deployment package for MVC project in solution with enabled nuget restore. When I write it manually if fails with different errors. But when I try to do it with visual studio 2012 (I click "Publish" and select "File System") it works just fine, so can I somehow to take a look at what VS does to build it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the verbosity of MSBuild:

### Via command-line:

```
msbuild myproject.csproj /v:diag > build.log
```

*or --*

### In Visual Studio:

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run:

[image: MSBuild verbosity]

Answer (score 1):

Redirect build output to log file and define required verbosity:

msbuild buildFile.msbuild /fileLogger /fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=LogFile.log;Verbosity=Diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8

[Verbosity types](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/msbuild/thread/43b87c20-f81a-4858-8a0f-7f4d1878f32f):

**Quiet**: only shows your the result of your msbuild.

**minimal**: shows some configurations of your msbuild, and the CSC task.

**normal**: This will show the all the targets and its mainly steps.

**Detailed**: In addition to normal, this target shows the the task and it's implementation within the each target.

**Diagnostic**: Contains all the information that a MSBuild need and produce, it's switch, parameter,prerequisite and etc. The input parameter of the target and task, and also contains the value of the input and output parameter, the detail steps of the task execution. The time execution for each task.